Selectively run jenkins pipelines based on the changes
I have a repo with multiple python packages inside. Each of them run in a different jenkins pipeline. These pipelines are always triggered from bitbucket using a webhook. I want to make adjustments to not run the pipelines when there are no changes to the folder of the package. I also dont want it to show as not  build, for clarity I want to see the status of the last time it ran. The webhook is sending this in the body
{
    "date": "2024-07-23T14:15:15+0200",
    "actor": {
        ...
    },
    "toCommit": {
        "committer": {
            ...
        },
        "committerTimestamp": 1721736909000,
        "author": {
            ...
        },
        "authorTimestamp": 1721736909000,
        "id": "eecf1f7634d9c0ccb1c7e48e7ea14e822197f77a",
        "displayId": "eecf1f7634d",
        "message": "working on generic triggers",
        "parents": [{
            "committer": {
                ...
            },
            "committerTimestamp": 1721734828000,
            "author": {
                ...
            },
            "authorTimestamp": 1721734828000,
            "id": "3dbe0065576c54a39764d870d85cb19163179d2e",
            "displayId": "3dbe0065576",
            "message": "working on generic triggers",
            "parents": [{
                "id": "3c53d71bf061dfa886b2c7c6d87ccb6b552334ec",
                "displayId": "3c53d71bf06"
            }]
        }]
    },
    "eventKey": "repo:refs_changed",
    "changes": [{
        "ref": {
            "id": "refs/heads/main",
            "displayId": "main",
            "type": "BRANCH"
        },
        "fromHash": "3dbe0065576c54a39764d870d85cb19163179d2e",
        "toHash": "eecf1f7634d9c0ccb1c7e48e7ea14e822197f77a",
        "refId": "refs/heads/main",
        "type": "UPDATE"
    }],
    "commits": [{
        "committer": {
            ...
        },
        "committerTimestamp": 1721736909000,
        "author": {
            ...
        },
        "authorTimestamp": 1721736909000,
        "id": "eecf1f7634d9c0ccb1c7e48e7ea14e822197f77a",
        "displayId": "eecf1f7634d",
        "message": "working on generic triggers",
        "parents": [{
            "id": "3dbe0065576c54a39764d870d85cb19163179d2e",
            "displayId": "3dbe0065576"
        }]
    }],
    "repository": {
        "archived": false,
        "public": false,
        "hierarchyId": "2639ba89f5b657028469",
        "name": "smart_charging_api",
        "forkable": true,
        "project": {
            "public": false,
            "name": ...,
            "links": {"self": [{"href": ...}]},
            "id": 2631,
            "type": "NORMAL"
        },
        "links": {
            "clone": [...
            ],
            "self": [{"href": ...}]
        },
        "id": 4684,
        "scmId": "git",
        "state": "AVAILABLE",
        "statusMessage": "Available"
    }
}

What are the options to do this?
I tried the generic-webhook-trigger, but the changes do not seam to appear in the body of the webhook.
